# Nifi issue in reading non-english(Chineese) character from oracle using executeSql

Tags: oracle11g, apache-nifi

We are facing issue in reading non-english (chineese) character using executeSql from oracle clob field. The character are getting converted to junk value. The executeSql works fine on varchar fields having such character but having issue with CLOB, NCLOB.

Have anyone faced this situation before and can you suggest a possible fix.

Comment: known issue: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-7410 workaround: use ExecuteSqlRecord

Comment: Hi Dagget we tried it already but executeSqlRecord is not bring clob data itself. We are on nifi 1.8. Do we need to upgrade?